# ssh remote port forwarding: connection refused

Tags: port-forwarding

Trying to etablish remote ssh port forwarding:

On my remote host, /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> GatewayPorts clientspecified

On my local computer:

```
ssh -g -R 1234:0.0.0.0:8000 me@my-remote-host
```

With debug, we can read:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to s1.bux.fr ([178.32.223.76]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:1234 forwarded to local address 0.0.0.0:8000
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 1234, connect 0.0.0.0:8000
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

On remote host, we can contact 1234 port (`WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3` is the local machine 8000 port):

```
# http :1234
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:26:00 GMT
Location: /accounts/login/
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

We can view opened port:

```
# netstat -tupln | grep 1234
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14460/1         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1234                :::*                    LISTEN      14460/1
```

But, from another machine in world, i'm unable to contact `my-remote-host:1324`:

```
# http my-remote-host:1234

http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my-remote-host', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb6b2fbec>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) while doing GET request to URL: http://my-remote-host:1234/
```

There is no firewall on my-remote-host:

```
# iptables -L
[sudo] password for bux: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-sshd  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

How found where it's blocking ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:1234    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   14460/1
```

Problem can be very well seen in the output of netstat. 
Your remote machine is listening on 127.0.0.1:1234, which is only available for local connection from that machine.

For ssh -g (gateway option) to work, you must specify wildcard address or some interface address reachable from the foreign client like:

```
ssh -g -R 0.0.0.0:1234:0.0.0.0:8000 me@my-remote-host
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution found is https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public:

We have to set bind address like this:

```
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:1234:0.0.0.0:8000 me@my-remote-host
```

Comment: Surprise - there is indeed no "-g" option needed, it worked from the moment on I used the bind address 0.0.0.0 - thanks

Comment: +1 to this answer, as it works to on Putty SSH client for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From `man ssh`:

> ```
>  -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.  If used
>          on a multiplexed connection, then this option must be specified
>          on the master process.
> ```

`-L` for *local* forwarding, and `-R` for *remote* forwarding. `-g` doesn't apply for remote.

Comment: Command executed without ``-g`` parameter produce same behaviour as presented in question.

Comment: Of course. The manual clearly says that `-g` doesn't have any effect when using `-R`.

Comment: Your response is off-topic. You should simply comment my question.

Comment: There is no any blocking at all. You listen on localhost (# netstat -tupln | grep 1234
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1234) and this is the reason why any other incoming connections get refused. ssh has no option for what you wanna do. Look for other solution!

Comment: I use this same command at work, on other remote host with no troubles. So there is an different configuration on the current remote host.

Comment: Found solution, see my anser. Is it possible finally. The -1 on my question is from you ?