# SOCKS connection through cygwin and proxy fails

Tags: ssh, proxy, cygwin, socks

I have serverA with a rhel 6 flavor with no connection to internet and serverB with Win Server and Cygwin that connects to internet through a proxy namely I can do something like `wget http://google.com` and get a response. I was looking for a way to redirect the internet connection with SSH and found this posts [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116867/serve-internet-to-remote-machine-via-ssh-session), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/262956/how-to-invoke-a-command-using-specific-proxy-server), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38755/how-to-download-a-file-through-an-ssh-server); particularly I'm trying to use `ssh -D 1080 user@serverB &` from serverA.

The ssh connection is stablished with no problems but when I try to issue `curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1 http://google.com` from serverA I get the following error `curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack` and in serverB `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`. I searched for the second error which seemed more promising and found [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open), [5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247788/channel-3-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open-failed-when-creating), [6](https://serverfault.com/questions/535412/how-to-solve-the-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open-failed-when-us). I checked and doubled checked that sshd_config had the appropiate configs and restarted cygwin sshd but the same errors appear when I try to reach any page. Here is my sshd_config:

```
$ grep -Ev '^(#.*|\s*)$' /etc/sshd_config
Port 22
StrictModes no
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
AllowTcpForwarding yes
PermitOpen any
PermitTunnel yes
X11Forwarding yes
PermitTTY yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
PermitTunnel yes
```

Am I missing any other config I should do in cygwin or windows? Is this even possible to be done with cygwin or I misread some of the threads I referenced?

Thank you